# Destroy / Pause Android Service (music) on HomeButton pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, background, onpause

I tried to add some Music in the Background of my Main Menu. I finally achieved it by using extends Service. Now i have another problem:

If the Home Button is pressed, the Service still runs and plays music, it only finishes, if i destroy it. I tried using:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
super.onPause();
service.setAction("model.BackgroundSound");
stopService(service);
}
```

which works fine, but if i switch from my Main Menu to my Character Selection Activity, it will pause too. But i would like to keep the music going in all Activities.
Is there a way to detect the difference of the App being "on pause" or just the activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments instead of Activities and it will call your Pause() just for the Single Activity.

Comment: Sorry but i only started learning Android programming like 1-2 Weeks ago and never really used fragments. How can i use fragments instead of Activities?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html go through this link it will help you to learn about the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API level 14 and higher you can use [registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) on the `Application`. You can check and example usage in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background/13809991#13809991).

This way you can check if any of your app's Activities is visible.